# Error messages not appearing inside of modal

Tags: users, forms

I have a registration form showing up in a Bootstrap modal.  I attached a validation function like so, which appears to be working, but when the page reloads, the error messages which I hope would appear in the `$messages` variable do not appear. When I reload the page (and resubmit the form), they do.

Here is the `form_alter` function snippet:

```
if($form_id == 'user_register_form'){
    $form['#validate'][] = 'form_styling_js_validation';

}
```

and that validation function looks like the following:

```
function form_styling_js_validation(&$form, &$form_state){
if(form_get_errors()){

$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
drupal_add_js('
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery( "#modal" ).modal( \'show\' );
      console.log(\'You failed validation!  Try again\');
    });', 'inline');
  }else{
    drupal_goto("introduction", array('query' => array('login' => 'success')));
  }
}
```

So, if there are errors, it injects that Javascript which opens up the modal. This is where a user should see all the error messages (e.g. "Password is required").

Here is the snippet of page.tpl.php where the modal lives:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="start-lesson" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title">Welcome. You'll need an account to continue.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Accounts are free and easy to set up.  Simply fill out the information below to get started</p>
        <div id="overlay-login-form">
            <div class="sign-in">
                <h2>Sign in </h2>
                <?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form("user_login"));?>
                <span><a class='cant-login' href='/user/password'>I can't sign in or I forgot my password</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="create-account">
                <h2>Create Account</h2>
                <?php if (!empty($messages)): ?>
                    <div id="messages">
                      <?php print render($messages); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form("user_register_form")); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing here? This validation is not happening via AJAX; I believe the page is reloading, and that `$messages` variable should not be empty.

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: <?php print render($messages); ?> show after page refresh.

Comment: @JalilKhan, I already have that php snippet in the page.tpl.php file above, right below Create Account.

Comment: i mean you use print render function directly in modal. which cant be display witout page refresh. you have to learn ctool module and its examples,

Comment: Sorry if the modal part is unclear. Everything inside the #modal div always shows up in every page, it's just hidden by default, until it gets shown via Javascript.

Comment: check this https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_modal_messages and https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter_bootstrap_modal

Comment: otherwise your $message will not be displayed.